# Extract image url when reading rss feed

Tags: android

I must extract an image's url when reading RSS feeds. I was told to use regular expressions but I didn't manage to build a correct pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You want to first

public class Utility {

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFile(String str)
{
    Bitmap bmImg=null;
    URL myFileUrl;
    try {
        myFileUrl = new URL(str);
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bmImg;

}
```

}

After whatever you get like

```
String str="www.fifa.com/img.jpg"
ImageView img=(Imageview)findviewbyId(R.id.img);

Bitmap bmp=Utility.getBitmapFile(str);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

After you see parsed image in ImageView

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was asking how to get the image url, that you use to build the bitmap object, from the "img src='http://assets.sport.ro/assets/protv/2011/01/07/image_galleries/11952/foto_size2.jpg' width='146' height='82' /" string that i get when parsing a rss xml file.

Comment: Your link not    worked     view-source:http://www.fifa.com/rss/index.xml                where u get this        <image><title>FIFA.com</title>                                            <url>http://www.fifa.com/imgml/rssheader.gif

   </url><link>http://www.fifa.com/index.html</link><width>139</width><height>28</height><description>FIFA.com RSS</description></image>                    where  <url> tag gives the link for image

Comment: Sorry. It's not a real link. I've used it to make a point. I wanted to say that all I want is to extract the image url from a link with that description ("img src='<url>' width='<size>' height='<size>'")

Comment: Me fresher so pls tell me which is the real link

Comment: I was using this rss: "http://www.protv.ro/rss/". As you can see under the description tag is the image url with the sizes and a text description.